# Why does parametric custom sql in Tableau give me different results?

Tags: tableau-api

The same query when parametrized in Tableau is giving me different results altogether. Has anyone faced this kind of issue? If yes then how you resolve it?

[image: the query]

[image: same query but different results]

Comment: Adding to the question- Same code hardcoded with the date gives me the right result whereas the moment I parametrize it changes altogether.

Comment: Hello, I think you need to give more information related to how you are "parameterizing" in Tableau.

Comment: what parameter do you add? how did you added data to a parameter[l

Comment: Agree with others, there isn't enough info here to answer your question.  I would post all relevant information.  If you want to look yourself you can compare the SQL statements by reviewing the [logs](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/viewing-underlying-sql-queries-desktop).